# Splitting of dataset based on number of rows in to multiple tables

Tags: c#, datatable, dataset

I have a situation where I need to Split dataset results in to multiple tables eventually in to an array based on number of rows. 
Ex: my dataset has 34 rows with a url column, I need to split 34 rows in to 4 data tables (10,10,10 remaining 4) and eventually add to an array. I am using a forms windows application. Itried something like below however every time i add records to array it adds entire dataset. Any help would be appreciated.

```
 private DataSet Process(DataSet ds)
        {


            string[] Array1 = new string[10];
            string[] Array2 = new string[10];
            string[] Array3 = new string[10];
            string[] Array4 = new string[10];


            int COunt = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView.Count;
            int NoOfArraysToCreate = COunt/10 + 1;

            for (int i = 0; i <= NoOfArraysToCreate; i++ )
            {
                if (i == 0)
                {
                    foreach (DataRow drs in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
                    {
                        List<String> myList = new List<string>();
                        myList.Add(drs["Url"].ToString());
                        Array1 = myList.ToArray();
                    }
                }
                else if (i == 1)
                {
                    foreach (DataRow drs in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
                    {
                        List<String> myList = new List<string>();
                        myList.Add(drs["Url"].ToString());
                        Array2 = myList.ToArray();
                    }
                }
                else if (i == 2)
                {

                    foreach (DataRow drs in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
                    {
                        List<String> myList = new List<string>();
                        myList.Add(drs["Url"].ToString());
                        Array3 = myList.ToArray();
                    }
                }
                else if (i == 3)
                {

                    foreach (DataRow drs in dsURLsList.Tables[0].Rows)
                    {
                        List<String> myList = new List<string>();
                        myList.Add(drs["Url"].ToString());
                        Array4 = myList.ToArray();
                    }
                }

}
```

Comment: In all if blocks you are looping thru all the rows of datatable and creating array out of it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are looping through all DataTable rows for each of your pages. 
I would suggest you only loop over your rows once:

```cs
private List<List<string>> Process(DataSet ds, int pageSize)
{
    List<List<string>> result = new List<List<string>>();

    int COunt = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView.Count;
    int NoOfArraysToCreate = COunt / pageSize + 1;

    IEnumerable<DataRow> collection = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Cast<DataRow>(); //I find it easier to work with enumerables as it allows for LINQ expressions as below

    for (int i = 0; i < NoOfArraysToCreate; i++)
    {
        result.Add(collection.Skip(i*pageSize)
                .Take(pageSize)
                .Select(r => r["Url"].ToString())
                .ToList());
    }

    Parallel.ForEach(result, (page) =>
    {
        Parallel.ForEach(page, (url) => {}); // process your strings in parallel
    });

    return result;//I see you convert your string arrays back to DataSet, but since I don't know the table definition, I'm just returning the lists
}
void Main()
{
    // this is just a test code to illustrate my point, yours will be different
    var ds = new DataSet();
    var dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("Url", typeof(string));
    for (int i = 0; i < 34; i++) {
        dt.Rows.Add(Guid.NewGuid().ToString());//generating some random strings, ignore me
    }
    ds.Tables.Add(dt);
    //---------------------------------------
    Process(ds, 10);// calling your method
}
```

of course there are ways to do it with for loops as well, but I'd leave that for you to explore. 
I would also say hardcoding table numbers into your method usually is considered a code smell, but since I don't know your context I will not make any further changes

Comment: I wanted to have all the data(URL) in my case and use parallel.invoke to process these URL's concurrently to speed up the process of checking the status of them. 
Intention was to have specific data in an array and pass it as an argument to multiple methods and invoke them at the same time.

Comment: Well, in here you've got your lists defined as result[0], result[1] and so on. You can convert them back to your arrays should you so desire.

Comment: I updated the answer with an option of how you can process your results concurrently. I guess in this case you don't even need to split the pages anymore?